# Registering a domain without an email address

Tags: domains, email, domain-registration, email-address

I am soon going to be getting a domain and setting up email addresses for me and a few of my partners in business. I personally do not want to be tied to my current Outlook.com email address and I don't want to have to use that address to manage my domain settings. I will not be using my old address once I have my personalized domain and email address. Are there any domain registrars that do not require and email address or allow you to change it later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**All Registrars Require Valid Email Addresses**

You will not find a registrar that does not require a valid email address, this is because its a requirement of the domain registration process and the regulator of the domain types require this information ([ICANN](http://www.icann.org/), [Nominent](http://www.nominet.org.uk/) etc). This is how they would contact you should there be a problem, complaint, etc.

**Changing Email Addresses**

You can change your email address should you want to use one that doesn't create spam in your important account, most changes take 24 hour to take place around the globe.

**Private Whois Information**

Should you not want to reveal your information to the rest of the world such as address, email, and telephone number then depending on the domain type [TLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain), [ccTLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code_top-level_domain) then you can opt to pay extra and hide the [whois](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whois) information, meaning only the registrar and regulator can see this information.

Comment: Note that some registrars like Gandi don't force you to pay extra for privacy, and offer [whois privacy by default](http://en.gandi.net/domain/whois/) to most registrants.

Answer (score 1):

Every registrar requires an email address to register a domain.

Every registrar will let you change your email address.

Therefore use your current email address to register and change it when you're ready.

Answer (score 1):

Just a little more information to add to the good answers already here:

ICANN requires valid contact information at the time of registration, so be sure not to use any made up or "fake" contact details. Often registrars will confirm the administrator's contact information, and if not possible, take over or delete the domain.

Domain renewal notifications are also sent to the administrator's email address, so if missing or incorrect can result in a hefty "redemption" fee or loss of the domain after it expires.

Lastly, be aware that ICANN prohibits the transfer of a domain for 60 days after the administrator's contact information is changed. Registrar's apply this differently, so it's best to check with them regarding changing the email if you plan on transferring the domain to another registrar within 60 days.

Private domain registration is a good option if you don't want to reveal your contact information. Tip: Look for discount codes to make this add-on less costly.